# Does html5 <video> supports .cgi format?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have to show live video from ip camera in my app.
    That video is in .cgi format.
    I am trying to use it in video tag so that it will also work on mobile.Is it possible ?

Comment: why downVote? correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it doesn't support *.cgi* (from which I've never even heard from) based on the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) that there are only **3 formats** supported: MP4, WebM and Ogg. Neither does [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) include .cgi as supported format.

Comment: thanks..Do you know ant other way to use .cgi format video in mobile devices?

Comment: @varun: Well, since I wasn't even able to find video format called cgi anywhere, I am quite confident that the browsers don't know how to handle it. Maybe you could be able to convert it first to some other known format and show it then?